# PyDev: Fatal error Python32\lib\io.py, line 60, in <module>

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev, eclipse-3.5

I work in PyDev and quite suddenly, I cannot run my python programs from within Eclipse's PyDev (version 2.1.0) anymore.

Any python program I have ran through *Run As > Python Run* fails wioth

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\io.py", line 60, in <module>

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

- I can still run my program in command Line, only Eclipse * I have only one version of Python (3.2)
- I haven't changed my python files since last time they worked. They are encoded UTF-8.
- I haven't upgraded Eclipse nor PyDev since last time they worked
- Python is installed in `c:\python32` (defined in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`)
- My XP system has been updated today for KB2536276 and

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found out where the problem came from: I had a file called `stat.py` and this is apparently creating a conflict with `Lib/stat.py`

Unfortunately the error message was very obscure.
And I just don't understand why pyDev behaves differently than python.exe

Comment: I have reported [bug 577329](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3423032&group_id=85796&atid=577329)

Comment: How did you fix the problem?

Comment: i simply renamed my module to a different name.