# PyCharm: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams

Tags: python, pycharm, attributeerror

I'm trying to use PyCharm IDE but none of my programs compile even simple Hello World. PyCharm gives this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\io.py", line 72, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ABCMeta'
Process finished with exit code 3
```

I'm not able to find the solution for it and also referred the link [PyDev: Fatal error Python32\lib\io.py, line 60, in <module>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111025/pydev-fatal-error-python32-lib-io-py-line-60-in-module) but there is no solution there.

Python 3.4 is installed on my Win 7 OS system.

Comment: Change your file's name from `io.py` to something else.

Comment: I solved my issue. Apparently PyCharm is not able to execute a file named `abc.py` because there is an in-built module called abc in Python. Executing `abc.py` via command line works. Check if your file is named `abc.py`, if it is, rename it to something else.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid can you explain more about why is that the issue and how to avoid it? I cannot find list of "reserved filenames" or anything similar.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Earlier I had named my package 'io'

Answer (score 84):

I faced the same problem because I created a file named `abc.py`, remove that file in your project, your error will disappear.

Comment: why the file name abc.py is not supported in pycharm?

Comment: If you name your file abc.py you're shadowing the [standard library's abc (abstract base class)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). When you do that, everything that depends on the built-in abc will get yours instead. Unless you've essentially rewritten the standard library's code, things will break.

Comment: Echoing @david-c, changing the name of the module may work, but it should not be necessary. Unchecking a few boxes in "Run/Debug" configurations is a better solution.

Comment: it worked fine for me..

Comment: Apparently same issue occurred while using PyInstaller and this answer saved me

Answer (score 18):

Yes, as you said in the comment, the problem is in the filename 'abc'. You will be able to run this file within PyCharm, if you uncheck:

- Add content roots to PYTHONPATH
- Add sources roots to PYTHONPATH

in the menu "Run/Debug Configurations".

Comment: This is what worked for me. I suspect it should be the accepted answer. There should be no magic-forbidden module names such as "abc.py".

Comment: Also worth checking to make sure the 'working directory' option isn't pointing to your file or subpackage.

Comment: In my case it was because the content root was a package installed to my local environment with `pip install -e .`.

Comment: It did not help me. Funny, that in my case it is only in Debug that I get this error.

Comment: I lost a whole afternoon to this, so thank you for posting this answer

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem, just change your file's name from io.py to something else, It's work!

Comment: This is just plain odd. I had to rename one of my packages its name was io and when debugging(and only then) would it not work! Afer changing to inout all worked.

Comment: LOL, i named a module 'io' as well

Answer (score 7):

Finally found how to solve this problem in PyCharm: never use a name like `abc.py` or `test.py`.

Simply use another name, like `a.py` or `my-unique-file-name.py`

Comment: this is strange. The python-stdlib is very large and python is supposed to be beginner-friendly, so the average programmer is not expected to know their module name clashes with the stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

try this:
File->Setting->Editor->File Encodings
change the Project encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

In my case `from .my_file import *` caused the error. Changing it to `from .my_file import func_1, func_2, func_3` solved it.