# Error occurred after updating and changing PYTHONHOME variable

Tags: python, pycharm

After changing some environmental variable for PYTHONHOME and updating pycharm and python my console kept spitting out this error:

```
def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, /, **kwargs)
                                          ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've search through some similar problems and tried to reinstall python and let it set the path but the problem still occurred.
For reference my first error that lead to this was akin to what happened int his question: [Fatal Python error on Windows 10 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512817/fatal-python-error-on-windows-10-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-encodings).

Then i tried the solution in this question: [Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams AttributeError: module 'io' has no attribute 'OpenWrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950533/fatal-python-error-init-sys-streams-cant-initialize-sys-standard-streams-attr)

And now i found myself with the above error of which am at a standstill. Ive tried looking for the syntax one would use for this **new** and perhaps found the error in there but so far no good.

Edit 1: Removed a / from _py_abc.py and it now says ImportError: cannot import name 'open_code'

Comment: what is the current value of your PYTHONHOME? Try opening a session in a terminal, then    $: export PYTHONHOME='' And then launch python in that same terminal, see what happend

Comment: The current value is C:\Users\Wally\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\ and i must admit am still very new to python and i am struggling to do your request.

Comment: Could You post the code, that produces the error here? Syntax Errors don't just appear, maybe the PYTHONHOME is a red herring. Or the expression ``new`` was added to python and you switched versions.

Comment: You  could also try to run your code here: https://repl.it/languages/python3 and see if it works.

Comment: The error happens with any code I've written before, any new code I write and no code at all. I believe its pycharm as I can run a program I had converted to an exe with pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error after I've installed and tried to use `python 3.8` in eclipse.
The exact line of code is inside the `_py_abc.py` module/file, and it contains a feature that was introduced in `python3.8`, the [positional only parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters).

In my case, the error was raised while `pylint` (which was installed with `pip2`/`python2`) was trying to ... lint, and persisted even after I've installed `pylint` with `pip3`/`python3` (which in my Ubuntu 18.04 WSL points to `python3.6`). I've managed to overcome the problem only after I've installed pylint explicitly with `python3.8`.

So, this whole ranting about `pylint` is only to explain how I got the error and how I understood the problem which basically is: *some thing inside the IDE is trying to use some pre-3.8 executable to run something that should be run with a python3.8+ executable*.