# Second installation of python will not run on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I already have python 3.8 installed but need to also install python 3.6 which installed without error.I would like to run python 3.8 with the command `python` anywhere in cmd and just run python 3.6 from the specific file `C:Python\Python36\python.exe` so did not add python 3.6 to PATH. However when I try to run python 3.6 I receive this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: can`t initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:Python\Python38\lib\abc.py", line 64, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_abc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:Python\Python38\lib\io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "C:Python\Python38\lib\abc.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "C:Python\Python38\lib\_py_abc.py", line 35
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, /, **kwargs):
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why when I run Python36/python.exe, it attempts to access python 3.8 modules. I have tried uninstalling and installing. Any ideas?

Comment: Are both python installation is in your environment variables. Also try to be explicit as to which version you need to use in cmd.`python 3.6` or `python 3.8`

Comment: @Aditya I have edited my question to try to explain that.

Comment: I'd suggest a virtual environment to avoid these kinds of issues

Comment: @DerekEden I don't thing I can make a python 3.6 virtual environment thought as I just cannot get it to run

Comment: When you have two (or more) versions of python installed you should add a shebang command at the beginning that specifies which version to run, then run scripts via the `py` command. See [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#python-launcher-for-windows) int he documentation.

Comment: what's the exact command you are using to use python 3.6?

Comment: @martineau I tried adding a shebang line, It runs with ```#! python3.8``` but I receive the same error with ```#! python3.6```

Comment: @Aditya I was trying to run it from ```Python36/python.exe``` where Python36 is the folder where python 3.6 is installed

Comment: The shebang line will have no affect unless you also run the script with the `py` command. You can also run just `py --list` to see what pythons are available.

Comment: @martineau when i was testing the shebang i did use the ```py``` command but received the same error as the one in the original question

Comment: Does `py --list` show that both python versions are installed? If not, you will need to reinstall the missing one.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950533/fatal-python-error-init-sys-streams-cant-initialize-sys-standard-streams-attr

Comment: @martineau yeah it shows both installs: ```Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.8-64 *
 -3.6-64``` but only 3.8 runs

Comment: @Aditya thanks very much, that link helped sort the issue. I just needed to remove PYTHONHOME environment variable

Comment: In that case it sounds like something is messed-up with the configuration of the two (or at least with v3.6). FWIW I use shebang lines like this `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6` in my own code on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the environment variables.
The `PYTHONHOME` environment variable was set to the python 3.8 directory. Once I deleted this variable, the problem was solved.

Comment: delete the one which is directing to lib folder