# csv Import error in Pycharm after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I need to install Anaconda for another project while I use Pycharm regularly. However, after I installed Anaconda, if I hit the run button on Pycharm for a python file (I'm using python 3.7.4), there is an import error. There was no problem before Anaconda was installed for the same code.

To illustrate, under the parent folder I created a folder named "io" (which is the same as built-in module) and the python file named "testandtest.py". The directory structure is like this:

- test_IO_error/

  - **init**.py
  - io/

    - **init**.py
  - testandtest.py

The code of "testandtest.py" is as below:

```
import csv
def foo():
    print ("This is a test!")
```

After I hit "run" button for testandtest.py in Pycharm, there is an error message:

> Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard
>   streams AttributeError: module 'io' has no attribute 'OpenWrapper'
>   Current thread 0x00046ccc (most recent call first): Process finished
>   with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

I assume this problem is because when importing `csv`, some files in `csv` module needs to import the built-in module `io`, but instead import the io module in the current folder, which of course does not have an attribute 'OpenWrapper'. But isn't it the case that python 3 is using absolute import always?

There is no problem if I run the function `foo` in console of Pycharm.

This problem only happened when run the code using the "run" button in Pycharm software.

Answer (score 0):

After searching many answers on line. I find a fix.

This is obviously  a module shadowing issue. However, I don't want to change the folder name from `io` to another one.

the fix is: go to Run --> Edit Configurations then uncheck

- Add content roots to PYTHONPATH
- Add sources roots to PYTHONPATH

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569828/pycharm-py-initialize-cant-initialize-sys-standard-streams) was fixed before.