# Can't run Python 3, io.py gives a AttributeError on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I tried to run Python3 on my Windows but it gives me a AttributeError from io.py.

I have tried both the Windows Store version and Download from https://www.python.org/downloads/

When I try to run `python3` or `py` in PowerShell 7.2.6 terminal I get

```
PS>python3
>Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program\Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\io.py", line 87, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'abc' has no attribute 'ABCMeta'
```

or

```
PS>py 
>Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\io.py", line 87, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'abc' has no attribute 'ABCMeta'
```

With troubleshooting I have tried a few things

1. To reinstall both from the Windows Store and the Download from https://www.python.org/downloads/, but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem.
2. Only run the store version or the download from the website.
3. I have tried to troubleshoot on the internet, but I don't see anything when it comes to running Python alone. And usually comes down to naming Python scripts which I don't want to run specificly.
4. I thought it could be a systen PATH problem in Windows, but that seems to be not the case as it still didnt work after I changed the path to "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310" and "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts".

And the problem seems to come from the io.py which can't see the attribute `ABCMeta` from the module `abc`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does running `py -3` work?

Comment: Also, what does running `where py`, `where python`, and `where python3` print? Please [edit] this information into your question.

Comment: it does work thanks! not sure on why but at least it solved my problem @MattDMo

Comment: The commands ```where py```, ```where python``` and ```where python3``` dont return anything in the terminal @MattDMo

Comment: What does `echo %PYTHONPATH%` print?

Comment: You must have a corrupted installation of Python somewhere on your PATH. Try running the `where` commands in CMD instead of PowerShell.

Comment: for me i just type `python`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm: Py\_Initialize: can't initialize sys standard streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569828/pycharm-py-initialize-cant-initialize-sys-standard-streams)